# Create installer/exe for c# .net core 3.0 project with dll

Tags: c#, dll, installation, .net-core-3.0

I need help how to create installer for c# .net core 3.0 project with some dll. I've tried the installer extension and Install shield for vs2019 but seems it is not working. Please help. Thanks.

Comment: I've tried this: [link](https://dotnetcoretutorials.com/2019/06/20/publishing-a-single-exe-file-in-net-core-3-0/) but i am getting **The task "ResolveComReference" is not supported on the .NET Core version of MSBuild.** error...

Comment: Try wix toolstet: https://wixtoolset.org it makes creation of installers very easy!